# Бот телеграмм не меняется переменная

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота телеграмм с помощью aiogram.

Объявлена переменная, но она никак не меняется из функции.

Как пробовал:

Объявляю глобальную переменную

```
question_type = 'Не выбран'
```

Затем пытаюсь изменить ее в функции

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback: callback.data == 'sub_menu_2_2')
async def sub_menu_1_2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, question_type):
# Создаем и отправляем клавиатуру с уровнем 3
question_type = 'Заказ звонка'


keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
back_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Отмена', callback_data='menu_level_2')
keyboard.add(back_button)
await bot.edit_message_text('Напишите свои ФИО и номер телефона ',
callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id,
                            reply_markup=keyboard)
```

В некоторых источника советуют добавить Global, но это вызывает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь с решением проблемы. Заранее спасибо

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin исправил

Comment: Читай ошибку. Что написано?

Comment: @Эникейщик уж не знаю почему не работало, видимо не подгрузилось. но проблема решилась сама собой

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, не прогрузились ресурсы. Спустя 20 минут ошибка перестала выскакивать.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Духсообщества ещё бы я сам знал))))

Comment: `@Дух сообщества` - это бот. Ему бесполезно что-то отвечать :)